# How do I make the text in the input start from the top?

Tags: html, css, forms

I have an input with a height and width more than regular. And the text starts at the center vertically and overflows to the right when I type in it. How do I make it so the text starts at the top-right corner and doesn't overflow past the width of the input without using JavaScript? I also don't want to use a textarea. Here is my code:

```css
.notesheet {
  background-color: rgb(224, 214, 67);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin-top: 300px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9c9898;
  border-radius: 15px;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<input class="notesheet"></input>
```

Comment: </input> <-- does not have a closing tag....

Comment: What you want to do is nearly impossible to do. Not all modern browsers will support wrapping of text in the input. Sounds like you need to use a textarea if you want this.

Comment: Yeah, I decided to use that instead, thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `<textarea>` tag?

you can use attribute `resize: none;` to prevent user change width and height

eg:

`​<textarea class="notesheet" rows="30" cols="50"></textarea>`

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that out

Answer (score 0):

if you are insisted to use `input` element there is a workaround for that like below:

```css
.notesheet {
    ... your css goes here
    background-color: rgb(224, 214, 67);
    position: absolute;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9c9898;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 500px;

    /* the point that i want to make */
    padding: 5px 5px 280px 5px;
    text-align: right;
}
```

instead of using `height` property, you can remove it and use padding to give input padding bottom of something like `280px` for making your text aligned to top section of the input. also for aligning it to stick it to the right, you can use `text-align: right;`.

but overall there is no clear solution in css for input element to act like `textarea` and wrap your words in it's boundary, or if there is, i don't know it yet!

Here is the code snippet that i tested and modified your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4xw6urjz/7/